# Is there a way I can add weight-age to specific fields in Mongo-db without indexing and aggregation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Document format :

```
[
    {
      "_id": "",
      "productId": "prod003",
      "productName": "Adbrief Indemnity",
      "productIconUrl": "",
      "type": "",
      "productType": "",
      "businessLineId": "Bus005",
      "description": "",
      "benefit": [
      ],
      "feature": [
        "1. Dashboard interaktif",
        "2. Web analytics AdMedika"
      ],

      "mediaId": [
        "Med001",
        "Med002",
        "Med003",
        "Med004"
      ],
      "documentId": [
        "doc001",
        "doc008",
        "doc003"
      ],
      "createdAt": "2019-07-12T06:16:00.229Z",
      "updatedAt": "2019-07-12T06:16:00.229Z"
    },
{
      "_id": "",
      "productId": "prod004",
      "productName": "Cash management",
      "productIconUrl": "",
      "type": "",
      "productType": "",
      "businessLineId": "Bus005",
      "description": "",
      "benefit": [
      ],
      "feature": [
        "1. Dashboard interaktif",
        "2. Web analytics AdMedika"
      ],

      "mediaId": [
        "Med001",
        "Med002",
        "Med003",
        "Med004"
      ],
      "documentId": [
        "doc001",
        "doc008",
        "doc003"
      ],
      "createdAt": "2019-07-12T06:16:00.229Z",
      "updatedAt": "2019-07-12T06:16:00.229Z"
    }
]
```

In a document like the one above, the find query should be working based on priority in the following order:

- productName
- description(lowest)
- feature(Latest)

I want to search for multiple fields with weightage in mongodb with priority in above

can someone helpme?

Answer (score 0):

Try using $or in aggregation or query level because of its short circuit  behavior and you can give your priority order in $or for which param to search first in document

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/#behavior

Here search is key you want to find in the database collection

```
$or:[
 {productName:{$regex:search,$options:'i'}},
 {description:{$regex:search,$options:'i'}},
 {feature:{{$in:[new RegExp(search)]}}}
]
```